# How do i run two rails projects on my machine simultaneously

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to be able to run two rails servers on one machine via vagrant and virtual box. I have the first set up and when i run

```
rails s
```

it returns the following with the site accessibly in my browser at http://localhost:3000/

```
=> Booting Thin
=> Rails 3.2.22.2 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
installing dummy notifier
Thin web server (v1.7.0 codename Dunder Mifflin)
Maximum connections set to 1024
Listening on 0.0.0.0:3000, CTRL+C to stop
```

Heres the vagrantfile for this instance:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  config.vm.box = "hashicorp/precise64"

  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 3000, host: 3000

end
```

I now have the second project in a different folder on my local machine. I have navigated to it initiated my vagrant box, completed all the set up steps and ran rails s again. Here I get:

```
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 4.2.3 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Puma 2.12.2 starting...
* Min threads: 0, max threads: 16
* Environment: development
* Listening on tcp://localhost:3000
```

Heres the vagrantfile for this instance:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  config.vm.box = "hashicorp/precise64"

  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080

end
```

I have been trying to investigate the the fact that it says "listening on tcp://localhost:3000" but if anyone can give me some pointers as to how exactly I can run the two projects from the same machine it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You have to run them on different ports.  rails s takes a port argument.

```
rails s -p 3001
```

will give you a server at port 3001 and so on.

Comment: Thanks for the input but its still not returning the site. Is there any further information you need which might help. I'm a tad confused by the vagrant file's but then again this may have nothing to do with it.

Comment: Are both projects running on Vagrant?  Do the 2 projects talk to one another?

Comment: No they have no need to. Just updating my question with the vagrant files.

Comment: What behavior are you expecting that you are not seeing?

Comment: With the Thin instance when i type http://localhost:3000/ it loads a site but for the Puma instance when i try different variations of this including http://localhost:3001 and 127.0.0.1:3001 i get "site cannot be reached".

Comment: You need to use telnet to connect to TCP ports.  https://support.symantec.com/en_US/article.TECH107919.html

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps try running the second server at port 8080, not 3001, since your second vagrant machine is set up like :

config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080

Answer (score 0):

I ended up running

```
puma -b tcp://0.0.0.0:3001
```

and my vagrantfile had the following:

```
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 3001, host: 3001
```

Thanks for the pointers though as they helped me to better understand the problem and find the solution.